# oracle and simpleJdbcInsert

Tags: java, oracle

```
public class JdbcTemplateItemRepositoryV3 implements ItemRepository {

  private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;
  private final SimpleJdbcInsert jdbcInsert;

  public JdbcTemplateItemRepositoryV3(DataSource datasource) {
    this.template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource);
    // table 명만 알면 어떤 컬럼을 가지고 있는지 메타데이터로 모두 알 수 있다. jdbcInsert얘는 한 번 훑어 본다 메타데이터를,
    this.jdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(datasource)
        .withTableName("item")
        .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
    // .usingColumns("item_name", "price", "quantity"); 이건 생략가능 simpleJdbc가 meta
    // data를 읽어서 알 수 있다고 ??
  }

  @Override
  public List<Item> findAll(ItemSearchCond cond) {
    Integer maxPrice = cond.getMaxPrice();
    String itemName = cond.getItemName();

    SqlParameterSource param = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(cond);

    String sql = "select * from item";

    if (StringUtils.hasText(itemName) || maxPrice != null) {
      sql += " where";
    }

    boolean andFlag = false;
    // add가 없어도 param에서 정리가 된다.
    if (StringUtils.hasText(itemName)) {
      sql += " item_name like '%' || :itemName || '%'";
      andFlag = true;
    }
    if (maxPrice != null) {
      if (andFlag) {
        sql += " and";
      }
      sql += " price <= :maxPrice";
    }
    log.info("sql={}", sql);
    return template.query(sql, param, itemRowMapper());
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Item> findById(Long id) {
    String sql = "select * from item where id =:id";
    try {
      // 파라미터를 map으로 줄 수 있다.
      Map<String, Long> param = Map.of("id", id);

      // 두 번째 인수로 파마미터를 준다.
      Item item = template.queryForObject(sql, param, itemRowMapper());
      return Optional.of(item);
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
      return Optional.empty();
    }
  }

  private RowMapper<Item> itemRowMapper() {
    // camel 변환 지원
    return BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Item.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Item save(Item item) {
    SqlParameterSource param = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(item);
    Number key = jdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(param).intValue();
    item.setId(key.longValue());
    return item;
  }

  @Override
  public void update(Long itemId, ItemUpdateDto updateParam) {
    String sql = "update item set item_name =:itemName, price =:price, quantity =quantity where id =:id";

    // 이렇게도 param을 넘길 수 있다. save에서처럼 해도 됨
    // SqlParameterSource 이건 인터페이스
    SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValue("itemName", updateParam.getItemName())
        .addValue("price", updateParam.getPrice())
        .addValue("quantity", updateParam.getQuantity())
        .addValue("id", itemId);

    template.update(sql, param);
  }
}
```

"I'm getting an error only when I try to save the data. My teacher is using h2 database, which doesn't seem to have any problems with primary key constraints, but I'm using Oracle database and encountering this error.
i don't know how to solve it..
please help me

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
PreparedStatementCallback; ORA-01400: NULL을 ("SUWAN"."ITEM"."ID") 안에 삽입할 수 없습니다 ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: NULL을 ("SUWAN"."ITEM"."ID") 안에 삽입할 수 없습니다

Comment: your insert command has not INSERT INTO instead it has NULL, but i can't see where the is constructed you should check the comand that was build